# Ignore all line-breaks sandwhiched between two vertial bars inside of mark-down language tables and treat one vertical bar as one vertical bar

Tags: feature-request, markdown

When I try to write mark-down language tables, line breaks are not usually allowed inside of the table.

[image: screen capture of the fully rendered table containing text in the bottom row which should be in the row second from the bottom]

```None
| Tag            |           Description | Code                                    | Result                                   | 
|----------------|-----------------------|-----------------------------------------|------------------------------------------|
| `<b>`          | Bold Formatting       | `<b>this is bold</b>`                   | <b>this is bold</b>                      |  
| `<blockquote>` | Block Quotation       | `<blockquote>text</blockquote>`         | <blockquote>text goes here</blockquote>  |
| `<br>`         | Line Break            | `espinaca <br> ajo <br> salsa de soya`  | 
espinaca <br> ajo <br> salsa de soya <br |
```

| Tag | Description | Code | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `<b>` | Bold Formatting | `<b>this is bold</b>` | **this is bold** |
| `<blockquote>` | Block Quotation | `<blockquote>text</blockquote>` | > text goes here |
| `<br>` | Line Break | `espinaca <br> ajo <br> salsa de soya` |  |
| espinaca ajo salsa de soya <br |  |  |  |

The text containing the strings `espinca` and `ajo` and `salsa de soya` is supposed to be in the same row of the table as `<br>` and `Line Break`

The feature I am requesting is that line-feeds and carriage returns inside of a mark-down language table be ignored if the line-breaks are located in between two vertical bars.

The new `|\r\n|` could similar to the old `|`  as far as parsing tables goes.

Do to word-wrapping inside of the editor, I cannot read tables very well while I am typing the tables.

We could insert a line-break just before or just after some of the vertical bars. Perhaps if we use a double vertical bar, all new lies or carriage returns between two vertical bars could be ignored.

```
| Tag              |
| Description      |
| Code             |
| Result           | 
|------------------|
|------------------|
|------------------|
|------------------|
| `<b>`            |
| Bold Formatting  |     
| `<b>this is bold</b>` |
| <b>this is bold</b>   |  
| `<blockquote>`        |
| Block Quotation       | 
| `<blockquote>text</blockquote>`  | 
| <blockquote>text goes here</blockquote>  |
| `<br>`         | 
| Line Break     | 
| `espinaca <br> ajo <br> salsa de soya`    | 
| espinaca <br> ajo <br> salsa de soya      |
```

```
| Tag              || Description              || Code                                    || Result                |
|------------------||--------------------------||-----------------------------------------||-----------------------|
| `<b>`            || Bold Formatting          || `<b>this is bold</b>`                   || <b>this is bold</b>   |
| `<blockquote>`   || Block Quotation          || `<blockquote>text</blockquote>`         || <blockquote>text</blockquote>  ||
| `<br>`           || Line Break               || `espinaca <br> ajo <br> salsa de soya`  || espinaca <br> ajo <br> salsa de soya      |
```

pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> to zoom out on a Windows machine does not make the tables any easier to read in the in-browser editors for [enter link description here](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com).

If you have permission to migrate questions, then feel free to migrate this question [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). The moderators on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) banned my account. I can't put the feature request on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I can't migrate your question until you address your ban. Please take a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: This would be explicitly incompatible with the [GitHub Flavored Markdown Specification: 4.10 Tables (extension)](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-), which SE implements. Your example is operating exactly as is described in the specification. IMO, it would be a bad idea to implement this. In addition to then being incompatible with the specification SE is using, it would also break an unknown number of already existing posts.